# How to write a class with smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Suppose I have a class:

```
class State {
  std::shared_ptr<Graph> _graph;
public:
  State():_graph(new Graph){}
};
```

With regards to [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), apparently no need to free _graph in destructor as it is a smart pointer. The question is, do I need to write copy constructor and assignment operator for it?

Considering following:

```
State s1;
State s2 = s1;
```

What will happen with the second line?

Looks like it will be `s2._graph = s1._graph;`, pointer shared, so we are safe?

Comment: Just on what you've shown, you're fine. You could explicitly declare those methods as '= default' to communicate you've done this knowingly.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "safe". In regards to memory leaks, double deletes, etc, then, yes, you are safe. If this class is to be used in a multithreaded environment, you've now introduced the possibility for subtle hidden shared, cross-thread state sharing that is unlocked, and not safe.

Comment: Read up on the [rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Answer (score 0):

Default generated copy ctors and assignment operators use the ones provided in the class members.

The `shared_ptr` [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) "shares ownership of the object".

The `shared_ptr` [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) replaces and shares.

If this is the behavior you want, their is no need to explicitly declare the copy ctor and the assignment operator.